# Understanding Math in Java: Method that returns the power of 2 of a passed Integer w/o using Java's Math class

Tags: java, math

**My Problem Instructions:** Create a method which determines if an integer argument is power of 2.  It should have the following heading:

```
private static int powerOf2(int aNumber)
```

If the number passed as the argument to your method is an integral power of 2, then return the power.  If the number passed in aNumber is not an integral power of 2 (or not a positive number) then return -1.

**Do not use any methods from Java's Math class.**

**My Question:** 
I dont understand what the problem is asking for, return the power of 2 of a integer then return the power converted? Im not even sure whats being asked.

**My Code:**

```
private static int powerOf2(int aNumber)
{
    if(aNumber % 2 != 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(aNumber + " is 2 raised to ");
        while (((aNumber % 2) == 0) && aNumber > 0)
        {
            // While aNumber is even and > 0
            aNumber /= 2;

        }
        System.out.print(+ aNumber);
        return aNumber;

    }
}
```

**Conclusion:** 
Really in depth explanation of what the problem is asking me to do, and what does it mean to check the power of 2?

Comment: 2 to the power of 3 is 8. If I now asked you to tell me the power of 2 which 8 is, what would you answer? If you cannot answer that it is time to ask the one giving you the assignment. because it is obviously not obvious. If you ask my opinion, I would answer 3.

Comment: @Yunnosch , I understand that. I just do not understand the Power of 2, because any number could be a Power of 2, then return it the full power of it? I don not understand that concept.

Comment: `1,2,4,8,16...  (in general - 2^k)` are integer powers of 2

Comment: You are repeating your question and do not understand my implication. So it is time to ask the instructor.

Comment: @Sun , what does 'sup' and 'pre' mean?

Comment: It is a failed attempt to use formatting in a format-restricted comment. Or the idea is  that you do html rendering in your head.

Comment: Thanks for everyone chipping in and helping, I understand now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asked for is to check if the number passed as an argument to the function is a power of 2, and if it is, what is the power of 2 that sums up to `aNumber`. (`2^x = aNumber`) - you want to find `x`.

For example if you pass 8 to the function, you should return 3, since `2^3 = 8`. But if the number isn't the power of 2, you should return -1 - for example if the parameter is 9, there is no integral power of 2 that can result in 9.

Regarding your program, you can make it work with some minor modifications:

What you want to do is make a loop and in every iteration check if the input number is dividable by 2 (`aNumber % 2 == 0`), and if it is divide it by two (`aNumber = aNumber / 2`). If you can get to 1 in this way, that means that your number is a power of two, and you just have to count the iterations (number of times you divided `aNumber` by 2). So your function might look like this:

```
private static int powerOf2(int aNumber)
{
    int power = 0;
    if(aNumber % 2 != 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print(aNumber + " is 2 raised to ");
        while (true)
        {
            if(aNumber % 2 == 0){
            aNumber /= 2;
            power++;
            if(aNumber == 1) return power;
            }else{
                return -1;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Ohhh, I see. You explained it and I understood  and it clicked:).  So, 9 cant be made using any form of the power of 2 ohhhhh, same for similar numbers. okay cool. I appreciate the help thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

Power of 2 means you can get the number by multiplying digit 2, for example:

- If the input is 1, then you should return 0 since 2<sup>0</sup> = 1;
- If the input is 2, then you should return 1 since 2<sup>1</sup> = 2 * 1 = 2;
- If the input is 4, then you should return 2 since 2<sup>2</sup> = 2 * 2 = 4;
- If the input is 8, then you should return 2 since 2<sup>3</sup> = 2 * 2 * 2 = 8;

...

If the input is 0 or negative, you should return -1;

If the input is not a power of 2(for example 3, 5, 7, 10), you should return -1;

Answer (score 1):

In maths base^exponent=term

Eg:2^3=8 here base=2,exponent=3 and term=8

What the problem will give you is a term and what it need is the exponent with base fixed as 2.It needs to have the case that term may not be possible with integer values for exponent

Eg:2^4.473=20(approx).For such cases it needs you to return -1 and for cases with integer exponents that is perfect powers of 2 it needs the exponent

Have a look at the code to understand

```
private static int powerOf2(int aNumber) {

        int cnt = 0;
        System.out.println(aNumber + " is 2 raised to ");
        while ((((aNumber % 2) == 0) && aNumber > 0)) {
            // While aNumber is even and > 0
            aNumber /= 2;
            cnt++;

        }
        if (aNumber == 1)
            return cnt;
        else
            return -1;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Such a method can use the [Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfTrailingZeros-int-) method. This gives the power of 2 *if* the number is an integral power of 2, and we can simply test to see if we're right.

```
public static int powerOf2(int aNumber) {
    int trailingZeros = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(aNumber);
    if (aNumber == (1 << trailingZeros)) {
        return trailingZeros;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method should return a number that represents an exponent.

If you input 8, the program should output 3 (since 2 x 2 x 2 = 8). If you input either a number that isn’t a power of 2, or is negative, it should output -1. Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

What the question means is basically how many 2s multiplied together will get you the number passed in.

If the number passed in is 8, then you return 3, because three 2s multiplied together, 2x2x2 is 8.

If not for the restriction of not using anything from the `Math` class, you could do this just by doing something like:

if (aNumber < 0) return -1;
   int power = (int)(Math.log(aNumber) / Math.log(2));
   return (int)Math.pow(2, power) == aNumber ? power : -1;

With the restrictions, you could do some bhtshifting, in addition to what other answerers have said.

```
private static int powerOf2(int aNumber)
{
    if (aNumber == 0) return 0;
    if (aNumber < 0) return -1;

    int count = 0;
    while (aNumber != 0) {
        int shifted = aNumber >> 1;
        if (shifted * 2 != aNumber) return -1;
        aNumber = shifted;
        count++;
        if (aNumber == 1) {
            return count;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```